# MVC3 globalization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, globalization

I'm developing a MVC3 application with the next culture setup:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"/>
```

First when I pass values from the view to the controller when I pass a integer all ok, but when I passed a double (3.2) the value in the controller was returned in 0 as was described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160557/how-can-i-get-a-double-from-the-view-into-my-model). Ok model binders added:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

  ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double), new DoubleModelBinder());
  RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

}
public class DoubleModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

If I use like default the culture "en-US" it's all okay but when I try to setup globalization to auto (that's what I need) my culture is "es-ES" and when I write "3,2" don't detect me field as a number. The problem and the answer is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825398/2662302): use the plug-in developed in jquery by microsoft and the model binder. The model binder don't fix my problem and the plug-in linked in the microsoft page don't work (broken link). What can I do?

**Update:**

I downloaded Globalize from nuget and added the lines according to this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) (I don't know why stackoverflow don't allow me to copy that code)

That deactivates all the validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For server side you must use this model binder:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                          ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
            {
                return 0m;
            }
            var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
            object actualValue = null;
            try
            {
                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(
                    valueResult.AttemptedValue.Replace(",", "."),
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                );
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
            return actualValue;
        }
```

And for client side take a look at this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682320/global-settings-for-jquery-valdiator-method)