# Global settings for jQuery valdiator method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am sorry for my simple question but I can't get it work .
How I can make this  jquery validator method to work globally .
I have this code in my layout:

```
jQuery.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(function () {
            Globalize.culture("ro-RO");
        });
    });
```

But this is not working in my partial views so to make this code to work I have to put this in all my partial views ...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Common/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Common/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    };
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(function () {
            Globalize.culture("ro-RO");
        });
    });
</script>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateSemifabricat_AddResourceToProduct", "Product", null,
        new AjaxOptions{
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,

        }, new { id = "addResToProd" }))
    {

      <input type="submit" value"Submit"/>

    }
```

So my question is how can I make this code to work globally?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you got a -1 for a poorly written question.  In the future, it would serve you best to refrain from using comments to complain and learn from your experience.  See: http://sscce.org for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `jQuery.validate.js` script, but it will add permanent dependency to `globalize.js`

find **this**:

```
return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
```

and replace with **this**:

```
return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
```